# How to make two bottom borders of div overlay?

Tags: css

Below are my html and css code

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-color: gray;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}

.label {
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-color: orange;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <div class=label>
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
```

It is the current outcome:

[image: ![enter image description here]

My ideal result is, however, to have the orange color border totally overlay the gray border of the `.container` div. Here is an illustration.

[image]

I have tried adjusted padding and margin but I cannot achieve my desired result because, obviously, theses changes will change the size of the container as well.

Is it possible to achieve it using css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add negative `margin-bottom` on `.label` equal to `border-bottom-width` of `.container` and some left / right `padding` if necessary:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-color: gray;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
}

.label {
  border-bottom-width: 2px;
  border-bottom-color: orange;
  border-bottom-style: solid;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
}
```

```html
<div class=container>
  <div class=label>
    Hello
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Didn't even know this attribute exists! Thanks! Will accept once the system allows.